# Other ways to drop a row in pandas based on specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to delete rows from a pandas df that are equal to 0, i only need that specific row's 0's to be deleted as other rows with a 0 value are ok. i have been trying different variations of code that i will list here to no affect. Anyone know why its not working or working incorrectly?

i have tried using:

```
df = df[df.Columnname != 0]
```

and

```
df = df['df.Columnname != 0']
```

i have tried changing the 0 values to NaN then dropping the NaNs like this:

```
columns = ['columnname']
df = df.replace('0', pd.np.nan).dropna(axis=0, how='any', subset=columns))
```

I've also tried different variations that i have found here in these forums to no affect. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happened with your first approach? That's the way to do it.  You could try using `loc`m but your method should work.  If I had to guess, you're running into floating point issues, in which case you need `np.isclose` or something

Comment: @rchurch4 mentioned to check your columns to make sure the name is correct

Comment: @user3483203 you were correct, they were still type: object and the first approach worked once i converted them to floats. Hopefully anyone else having this issue reads this and finds out they need to be floats or maybe even ints to use this appraoch df= df[df.columnname !=0]    thanks so smuch you helped a ton!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all rows with all NaN values, the you can use 'how' parameter

```
df.dropna(how='all')
```

If you pass how='any', it will delete all rows which have even at least one column with NaN value.
Please specify with a snippet, if you want to delete by specifing column or a particular row.

Comment: This isn't what they want.